# What is the Big O complexity of this algorithm

Tags: java, big-o

I can't seem to figure out the time complexity for this algorithm. I know that the while loop will execute at O(log n) times because n keeps halving. But I'm not super sure how to represent the time complexity of the inner for loop.

```
while(n>0){
   for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        System.out.println("*");
   }
   n = n/2;
}
```

Comment: The point here is that `n /  2` actually becomes `0` for an `int n = 1;`. In theoretical maths it will of course never become `0`, but in Java it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each while loop divides `n` by `2`.

Therefore, the first for loop would run `n` times, the second for loop would run `n/2` times, the third for loop would run `n/4` times, and so on.

If we set `n` to an arbitrary large value, then the complexity would be:

`n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + n/32 + ... = 2n`

Of course, `n` is an integer, and programmatically, the division would result in 0 after enough repetitions.

Therefore, the time-complexity of the algorithm would be `O(2N)` = `O(N)`

Answer (score 2):

We can figure out the complexity of both loops by inspection.  For an input of n = 8, the inner loop would print out this many stars at each iteration:

```
8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15 ~ 2^4
```

For n = 16:

```
16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 31 ~ 2^5
```

The complexity here is:

```
O(2^([log_2(N)]+1)) = 2*O(2^log_2[N])
                    = O(N)
```

We can see that at each step the number of print statements is roughly *twice* the value of the input `N`.  So the overall number of print operations is actually `O(N)`, which is linear in the actual value of the input `N`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets `n₀` be the start value of `n`.
At the `i-th` (from 0) iteration of the while loop, `n = n₀ * ½ⁱ`
The cost of one iteration of the while loop is `n` (because of the `for` loop)

Hence the global cost is: *sum for i from 0 to whatever of n₀ * ½ⁱ*
Or: *n₀ times the sum for i from 0 to whatever of ½ⁱ*

The sum is a [sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum), and is less than 2.

Hence the global cost is *O(2.n₀)* or *O(n₀)*